# Canon EOS 600D screen froze and now not starting

Tags: canon

I was trying to use my EOS 600 D after around 6 months today. When I switched it on in the morning, it was working fine and the. The LCD screen froze. I switched off the camera but still the LCD screen remained on. So I took out the battery to switch off the LCD. Since then I am unable to switch on my camera. I have charged the battery to full and nothing.. I went to a store and tried with a new battery, still couldn’t get it on. The store guy told me that there is no option but to visit the service center.

I have read that many people faced similar issues in the past but wasn’t able to get to an answer which would resolve my problem. Can someone help please.

Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

If leaving the battery out for a day or so doesn't force it to 're-think' then you've no choice but a service centre; though weigh cost of repair against cost of replacement.

You can get one of those 2nd hand for $£€ 170.

<sup>That is, unless someone has some tricksy way to force a reset without being able to access the menus…</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You already have the only answer that makes sense. The person at the camera store gave it to you:

**You need to send the camera to a competent technician and let them diagnose the problem with your camera.**

If that will cost more than you are willing to spend on this camera, then it is time to move on to another camera.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with mine not switching on because of a faulty memory card. Try removing the card and battery in switched off state, then inserting battery only and switching on.